# Generating a table with docx from a dataframe in python

Tags: python

Hellow,

Currently I´m working in a project in which I have to generate some info with docx library in python. I want to know how to generate a docx table from a dataframe in order to have the output with all the columns and rows from de dataframe I've created. Here is my code, but its not working correctly because I can´t reach the final output:

```
    table = doc.add_table(rows = len(detalle_operaciones_total1), cols=5)
    table.style = 'Table Grid'
    table.rows[0].cells[0].text = 'Nombre'
    table.rows[0].cells[1].text = 'Operacion Nro'
    table.rows[0].cells[2].text = 'Producto'
    table.rows[0].cells[3].text = 'Monto en moneda de origen'
    table.rows[0].cells[4].text = 'Monto en moneda local'

    for y in range(1, len(detalle_operaciones_total1)):
        Nombre = str(detalle_operaciones_total1.iloc[y,0])
        Operacion = str(detalle_operaciones_total1.iloc[y,1])
        Producto = str(detalle_operaciones_total1.iloc[y,2])
        Monto_en_MO = str(detalle_operaciones_total1.iloc[y,3])
        Monto_en_ML = str(detalle_operaciones_total1.iloc[y,4])

        table.rows[y].cells[0].text = Nombre
        table.rows[y].cells[1].text = Operacion
        table.rows[y].cells[2].text = Producto
        table.rows[y].cells[3].text = Monto_en_MO
        table.rows[y].cells[4].text = Monto_en_ML
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't reach the final output"?

Comment: Hi, I mean I cannot obtain the table with all the columns and the rows from de dataframe